# image/content not contained inside div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to contain an image inside the first div of this page and it's outside of it for some reason. All the assets are in a flexbox. It works completely fine when I put text inside that div but not an image.

I've circled in red which image and div I'm talking about.
The code snippet won't show you what I'm talking about since it isn't the full code.

[image][image]

```css
.landing {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
 
}
.introWrapper {
  width: 1000px;
}

.intro1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Yapari';
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 23px;
}
.intro2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Yapari';
  /* font-weight: 72; */
  margin-top: 50px;
}
#introCircle {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 230px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: auto;
}
.icons {
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: 50px;
}
.icon1 {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id='landing' className={styles.landing}>
      <div className={styles.introWrapper}> 
        <div className={styles.icons}>
          <img src={icon1} className={styles.icon1}/>
        </div>
        <div id={styles.introCircle}>       
          <h1 className={styles.intro1}>HELLO I'M</h1> 
        </div>       
        <LastName />
          <h1 className={styles.intro2}>A FULL STACK DEVELOPER</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: So basically you want to put "Hello I'm" inside the bordered box?

Comment: No that's something else. I want to put the little "x" image in the box.

Comment: Is that little "X" is the `<LastName />` component ? And the box should be the div with `styles.icons` right ? and you want to put the X inside that div? (I just want to be clear about the issue)

Comment: The "x" is the `<img src={icon1} className={styles.icon1}/>` and yes I would like to put it inside the `styles.icons div`

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have provided a height to the div "icons" . change the `height` to `min-height`

```css
.icons {
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah that still doesn't work :/

Comment: you have not provided all the details and code. therefore its difficult to interpret the problem you are undergoing. Provide some more details

Comment: Here is the github repo with all the code: https://github.com/hiashley/Ashley-Yu-React-Portfolio